# How to find unused Java classes and JSP files from a project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

How do I find unused Java classes and JSP files from a project?

I am using Eclipse and [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) as the source control system.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Mercurial? Please remove the tag if you agree, or expand the question to explain where Mercurial fits into this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [CodePro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/) will do what you want.

Also a quick way of identifying this if only on a few files is right click the file and select 'References' then workspace or project.

Answer (score 1):

[ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) will do this as part of its "listing dead code" feature.  The [examples page](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html) shows you exactly how to do it.

Answer (score -2):

It could be approached for an unused class in projects. See how Eclipse marks the Eclipse unused classes as yellow. As it is open source, it is easily available.