# How to delete unused JSP and action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

My project use Struts2, Spring and Hibernate.

And the project grow bigger and a lot of action never used. 
So related tiles and JSP also have the same issue.

Is any tools or write some code to find out all unused link. 
Or found the link can be reach from index page and then go though all action . found the unused action.

My action is like below :

```
    @Action(value = "saveClass", results = {@Result(name = SUCCESS, type = "tiles", location = ".initStep3"),
            @Result(name = "repeat",type = Constants.RESULT_NAME_TILES,location = ".repeatClassInfo"),
            @Result(name = "maintenance",type = Constants.RESULT_NAME_TILES,location = ".courseInfoModified"),
            @Result(name = INPUT, type = "tiles", location = ".saveClass")})
    public String saveClass() {
```

Comment: Define unused link and unused action.

Comment: used link means: my website start from index.html.   index.html has hyperlink "test.html", test.html can post data to test2.html. and after post, websit will redirect to test3.html and also sometimes redirect test4.html. Those links are used links.   For other unreachable links are unused link.

Comment: BTW: for jsp. if no tiles or action referenced. we trade it as unused.

Comment: For Link and action.  link is index.html.  action is Class: HomeAction.java method: index

Comment: Take a look at the `Config Browser Plugin` for the hints how to get S2 configuration.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Config Browser Plugin only get S2 configuration, can't help me this action is really used my system. I mean can trace from index page.

Comment: I mean you can write your own logic for finding unused actions, etc... `Config Browser Plugin` is just for a hints how to get S2 configuration.

Comment: OK, Thanks. I am looking for a tool. The logic is complex, many case need be care and will be cost huge time, waiting if any good tools for this issue:)

Answer (score 0):

To find dead codes and unused methods
An Eclipse plugin that works reasonably well is [Unused Code Detector](http://www.ucdetector.org/).

Here is

1. [unnecessary-code-detector](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/unnecessary-code-detector)
2. [UCDetector](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/632719)

Maybe this will help...

Also see [How to find unused Java classes and JSP files from a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279479/how-to-find-unused-java-classes-and-jsp-files-from-a-project)

But for `struts.xml` configuration and dead links finding as <kbd>**Alexander M**</kbd> suggested use [Config Browser Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/config-browser-plugin.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don’t think can solve my issue.
config browser only can help me know which action I configured. But can’t help me know whether was used in my system.
What I want is :　Is any tool can help scan all reachable link from index.html, it’s similar to what google dose. When I know which link I already used. E.g. test1.html, test2.html…. I also can use this tool to search my action class, if I found test3 which not existing in my use link list (test1,test2). I can trade this action is unused and delete this method.

Comment: I can see my code "@Action(value = "saveClass" this action. convert to  link will be saveClass.html. how i can reach this link is click login.html and login to system.  click class menu and fill data and save class data. So this action has used by our system. If other action cannot trace from index. I will trade it unused action method.